# jQuery: Open File Upload window by pressing a link or image.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mootools

Is this possible to open a File Upload window when clicking on a image or link. (like what exactly in the `<input type="file" name="upload" />`).

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the [jQuery ajax upload plugin](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/). It allows to upload files via "ajax" (technically not really, but the effect is the same) and doesn't use input buttons (technically it does, but they are invisible).